# Encoding in Java

Tags: java, encoding

I have an C# function which i want to translate in Java code. I have a problem here:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");

bytZeichenBenutzer = enc.GetBytes(strBenutzer.Substring(intLoopCount, 1).ToCharArray());
```

How to do that in Java? I can't find anything similar only stuff that works with UTF-8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`getBytes(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) or [`getBytes(Charset)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) methods:

```
String myString = getMyStringFromSomeWhere();
byte[] utf8Bytes = myString.getBytes("UTF-8");
// or
Charset myCharset = Charset.forName("Windows-1252");
byte[] windowsBytes = myString.getBytes(myCharset);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "hhh"; 
try {   
  s.getBytes("Windows-1252"); 
} catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) { 
  e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
byte[] a = "some string".getBytes("Windows-1252");
```